# Android if statement evaluates false when UUIDs are identical

Tags: android, if-statement, bluetooth

See the attached image and code below.  I am checking to see if a Bluetooth device has an SPP UUID.  It does, and says it does, but the statement evaluates as false anyways.  The same is true if I break out the UUID name and evaluate it.

```
Parcelable[] uuids = device.getUuids();
                        if(uuids != null) {
                            for (Parcelable parcelable: uuids) {
                                ParcelUuid parcelUuid = (ParcelUuid) parcelable;
                                UUID uuid = parcelUuid.getUuid();
                                String str = SPP_UUID.toString();
                                String cmp = parcelUuid.getUuid().toString();

                                if (uuid.equals(Constants.SPP_UUID)) {
                                    isSPP = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

[UUIDS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9STb.jpg)
Please help, this is very frustrating as it seems so basic.
Thank you,
Tom

Comment: What is the data type of `SPP_UUID`?

Comment: Data type is UUID.  Tom

Comment: The same issue happens if I use the two strings (str and cmp).